# Hide a certain category name without removing it?

Tags: categories

I have a category called `feature` which I use to have a feature post in the homepage. The problem is I don't want the category name `feature` to appear in this posts, but I want the other categories to show up.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this we need to use `get_the_category` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category).
I am going to use this code in several places, so it is more efficient to create a function

```
function exclude_cats($excludedcats = array()){

    $categories = get_the_category();
    $separator = ', ';
    $output = '';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if ( !in_array($category->cat_ID, $excludedcats) ) {
            $output .= 'term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.''.$separator;
        }
    }
    echo trim($output, $separator);

}
```

All that I've done inside the function was to call `get_the_category` function, But I've excluded the categories I don't want to show their names to not show.

inside the index I've called the function like so `exclude_cats(array(11, 40, 53));`

Answer (score 1):

I think @Lafif Astahdziq was on the right track - I like his approach even though it is fairly static. Here is how I rewrote it:

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'hide_categories_terms', 10, 3);
function hide_categories_terms($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy){

    // define which category IDs you want to hide
    $excludeIDs = array(6);

    // get all the terms 
    $exclude = array();
    foreach ($excludeIDs as $id) {
        $exclude[] = get_term_by('id', $id, 'category');
    }

    // filter the categories
    if (!is_admin()) {
        foreach($terms as $key => $term){
            if($term->taxonomy == "category"){
                foreach ($exclude as $exKey => $exTerm) {
                    if($term->term_id == $exTerm->term_id) unset($terms[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $terms;
}
```

Put this in your functions.php and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `get_the_terms` filter like this,,

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'hide_categories_terms', 10, 3);
function hide_categories_terms($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy){

    // get term to exclude by name, by id or maybe by slug
    $exclude = get_term_by('name', 'feature', 'category', ARRAY_A);

    if (!is_admin()) {
        foreach($terms as $key => $term){
            if($term->taxonomy == "category"){
                if(in_array($key, $exclude)) unset($terms[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $terms;
}
```

i think it should works,,

Comment: I don't really understand how this could work. What the `$post_id` has to do with everything else?

Answer (score 0):

An old question but still quite popular so I have added another solution to add to your theme's functions.php file.

```
function hide_feature($query){
    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()){
        //negate the ID of the 'feature' category e.g. '-6'
        $query->set('cat', '-6');   
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_feature' );
```

Comment: As of WordPress 5.01, I've tried this, and it does not appear to work.

Comment: Hi, I've had a look through the code for this on WordPress github and nothing has changed recently but only certain fields (those with IDs) can be negated this way. Also there can be no space between the dash and the number. The code specifically for categories can be found here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/04dff0e2a969228bc80d9b1961136eef4edc583b/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1124

Comment: Thanks Andy. I'll have a look into that. Very much wanting to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of the [answer by Stefan Wimmer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/230921/142943):

```php
add_filter('get_the_terms', function ($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy) {
    // from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/230921
    $exclude_categories = array(45);
    if (!is_admin()) {
        foreach($terms as $key => $term){
            if($term->taxonomy == "category" && in_array($term->term_id, $exclude_categories)) {
                unset($terms[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}, 100, 3);
```

I think that the call to `get_term_by` can be omitted and used `in_array` instead of a loop.